# Install library / package in python

Tags: python, linux, package, installation

I'd like to install python bayesian_changepoint_detection, but I can't find instructions for how to install:

https://github.com/hildensia/bayesian_changepoint_detection

I tried

```
conda install bayesian_changepoint_detection
```

and

```
pip install bayesian_changepoint_detection
```

but it didn't work. Do you know how I should install it? My OS is Ububntu 14.04 LTS. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the install from Github::

```
pip install git+git@github.com:hildensia/bayesian_changepoint_detection.git
```

or

```
pip install git+https://github.com/hildensia/bayesian_changepoint_detection.git
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the content of the package in Github, I see `setup.py`, which means, that this module should be installed from terminal(after you've downloaded the package), like so:

```
python setup.py install
```